# mysql order by date hardcoded to bad format

Tags: mysql

dates are stored in the database as

```
    | mm-dd-yy | content | content | content|
    | mm-dd-yy | content | content | content|
    | mm-dd-yy | content | content | content|
    | mm-dd-yy | content | content | content|
```

what syntax would be used to ORDER BY `date` ASC while taking the year into account?

Edit: there are over 20,000 records stored this way and the application built on the data requires the date to be formatted this way, otherwise i would just change them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `str_to_date()`:

```
order by str_to_date(col, '%m-%d-%Y')
```